# NSPredicate for NSFetchedResultsController when searching a relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am working with an NSFetchedResultsController. I want to display in a table view all the Lions in a Zoo, where lions is a to-many relationship of Zoo. There could be thousands of Lions, so I need a batch size of 20.

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSPredicate* predicate = ???

        NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Lion" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
```

How do I set up the predicate? I already have the Zoo object. I just need all its Lions.

Answer (score 0):

As you know `NSPredicate` is a class that specifies how data should be fetched or filtered.

`NSFetchRequest` has a predicate property, which specifies the logical conditions under which managed objects should be retrieved.

Here's a great example on how you can use it with Core Data - http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that a `Zoo` entity has a relationship named `lions`.

```
Zoo *sanDiegoZoo = ...

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Lion"];

[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", sanDiegoZoo.lions]];

[request setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```